# Removing rows in a dataframe where first word of first column is lowercase

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) that has duplicates, one lowercase and one upper, from which I wish to delete every row where ONLY the FIRST COLUMN (df$a), has the first word lowercase. Thank you.

I have scoured the internet but this scenario seems unique. :)

Comment: `df[tolower(df$a)!=df$a,]`?

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
first_word_lowercase <- 
    function(sentence){w1 <- gsub('(\\w+).*', '\\1', sentence)
        ifelse(w1 == tolower(w1), TRUE, FALSE)
    }


d <- data.frame(first_col = c('Keep me', 'drop me'),
                second_col = 1:2
                )
```

```
## > d
##   first_col second_col
## 1   Keep me          1
## 2   drop me          2
```

```
subset(d, !first_word_lowercase(first_col))
```

```
##   first_col second_col
## 1   Keep me          1
```